# Printing a text file using perl

Tags: perl, printing

I am completely new to this and this should be the easiest thing to do but for some reason I cannot get my local text file to print.  After trying multiple times with different code I came to use the following code but it doesn't print.

I have searched for days on various threads to solve this and have had no luck.  Please help.  Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$newfile = "file.txt";
open (FH, $newfile);

while ($file = <FH>) {
         print $file;
}
```

I updated my code to the following:

```
#!/user/bin/perl

use strict;            # Always use strict
use warnings;          # Always use warnings.

open(my $fh, "<", "file.txt") or die "unable to open file.txt: $!";
                   # Above we open file using 3 handle method
                   # or die die with error if unable to open it.
while (<$fh>) {        # While in the file.
     print $_;     # Print each line
 }
close $fh;             # Close the file

system('C:\Users\RSS\file.txt');
```

It returns the following: my first report generated by perl. I do not know where this is coming from. Nowhere do I have a print "my first report generated by perl."; statement and it definitely is not in my text file.

My text file is full of various emails, addresses, phone numbers and snippets of emails.

Thank you all for your help. I figured out my problem. I somehow managed to kick myself out of my directory and did not realize it.

Comment: `use warnings; use autodie;` should be helpful. Also `use strict;` has great benefits.

Comment: could you please update the question what contains in the `file.txt` file

Comment: Your code is working fine at my end.

Comment: Ok, then I have no idea what is going on because I have 14,000KB of data in my text file and I can't get any of it to print

Comment: @R.Stone Please try and stick to one point at a time. You are going all over the show with comments. I am trying to show you your problem in the below answers', comments. Please give me the exact ouput as requested, not just _it gave me something something like_ answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a combination of a failure to open the file, and a failure to check the return value of `open`.

If you are completely new to perl, I warmly recommend reading the excellent "perlintro" man page, using either `man perlintro` or `perldoc perlintro` on the command line, or taking a look here: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html.

The "Files and I/O" section there gives a good and concise way of doing this:

```
open(my $in,  "<",  "input.txt")  or die "Can't open input.txt: $!";

while (<$in>) {     # assigns each line in turn to $_
     print "Just read in this line: $_";
}
```

This version will give you an explanation and abort if anything goes wrong while trying to open the file. For example, if there is no file named `file.txt` in the current working directory, your version will quietly fail to open the file, and afterwards it will quietly fail to read from the closed file handle.

Also, always adding at least one of these to your perl scripts will save you a lot of trouble in the long run:

```
use warnings; # or use the -w command line switch to turn warnings on globally
use diagnostics;
```

These won't catch the failure to open the file, but will alert on the failed read.

In the first example here you can see that without the diagnostics module, the code fails without any error messages. The second example shows how the diagnostics module changes this.

```
$ perl -le 'open FH, "nonexistent.txt"; while(<FH>){print "foo"}'
$ perl -le 'use diagnostics; open FH, "nonexistent.txt"; while(<FH>){print "foo"}'
readline() on closed filehandle FH at -e line 1 (#1)
    (W closed) The filehandle you're reading from got itself closed sometime
    before now.  Check your control flow.
```

By the way, the legendary "Camel Book" is basically the perl man pages formatted for paper printing, so reading the perldocs in the order listed in `perldoc perl` will give you a high level of understanding of the language in a reasonably accessible and inexpensive manner.

Happy hacking!

Comment: Thank you. I have the Camel Book and several others.  I had no problem opening other files last week so I have no clue what is going on.

Comment: Ok, I tried all the above and still nothing prints.  I created new .txt files to make sure the file I am trying to open isn't corrupt or something and with the diagnostics it says I don't have access to my own files.... I did this with no problem just a few days ago so no clue what is happening... and I tried this on two different laptops to double check ... neither allows me to open the files I want to print

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and including explanations.

```
use strict;            # Always use strict
use warnings;          # Always use warnings.

open(my $fh, "<", "file.txt") or die "unable to open file.txt: $!";
                       # Above we open file using 3 handle method
                       # or die die with error if unable to open it.
while (<$fh>) {        # While in the file.
         print $_;     # Print each line
 }
close $fh;             # Close the file
```

There is then also the case where you are trying to open a file which is not in a location where you think it is. So consider doing full path, if not in the same dir.

```
open(my $fh, "<", 'F:\Workdir\file.txt') or die "unable to open < input.txt: $!";
```

**EDIT:** After your comments, it seems that you are opening an empty file. Please add this at the bottom of that same script and rerun. It will open the file in `C:\Users\RSS` and make sure it does actually contain data?

```
system('C:\Users\RSS\file.txt');
```

Comment: Ok,  tried all the answers provided on this thread and I still cannot get the file to print.  I even created a new file and tried to use that one and nothiing.... it doesn't throw an error just nothing from the file prints.  I added a print "done\n"; at the end and that prints just fine but nothing from the file. I am at a complete loss.

Comment: @R.Stone The `die` should have given you an error, what is it?

Comment: No, nothing.  It just runs and then a new line in the cmd prompt appears and looks like this C:\Users\RSS>

Comment: @R.Stone then there is nothing in your `file.txt` ? made sure that `C:\Users\RSS\file.txt` has data in it?

Comment: @R.Stone Please do this... At the bottom of your script, add `system('C:\Users\RSS\file.txt');` Which will launch the same file file you are attempting to read from, does that file show content when it opens after you run the script?

Comment: I added the system line to the bottom of my script. It printed "my first perl something or another....." I have no idea where that came from because it is not what is in my txt file.  My text file is 14,825KB of information and I can't get any of it to print

Comment: @R.Stone ok, let's take a step back here please. Where exactly is this perl scrtipt located? Where exactly is `file.txt` located? Giving an example error does not help, you need to give the actual error. So please copy the message you received and not just _It printed "my first perl something or another_ if you give the actual output I can see where the issue is.

Comment: The message is: my first report generated by perl  ... again, I do not know why it is printing this. I have nothing like this in my script to print and this is definitely not in my text file.  I have a folder on my laptop that contains my .txt file and my .pl file they are in the same location.  When I open the .pl file in atom and run it using my cmd prompt nothing happens but when I write a print 'done' after my while loop this prints in my cmd prompt.

Comment: @R.Stone ok. now do me a favour. Edit your question and add the method you use to call the script as well as some content of file.txt and exact content of the current .pl file.

Comment: Ok, I will try but not sure if my changes in a few minutes is what you are looking for.

Comment: I updated the question with some information about the file and what is being returned

Comment: @R.Stone How do you execute the command? from cmdline? by double clicking it? please show me exactly. You are not calling the correct file it seems.

Comment: @R.Stone So I need you to also show me the EXACT path to the `.pl` script and to the `.txt` as well as show me EXACTLY how you execute the `.pl` script.

Answer (score -2):

First, of all as you are starting out, it is better to enable all warnings by 'use warnings' and disable all such expression which can lead to uncertain behavior or are difficult to debug by pragma 'use strict'.

As you are dealing with file stream, it is always recommended to the check if you were able to open the stream. so, try to use croak or die both would terminate the program with a given message.

Instead of reading inside the while condition, I would recommend checking for end of file. So, loop breaks as end is found. Usually, when reading a line you would use it for further processing, so it is good idea to remove end of lines using chomp.

A sample for reading a file in perl can be as follows:

```
#!/user/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $newfile = "file.txt";
open (my $fh, $newfile) or die "Could not open file '$newfile' $!";
while (!eof($fh))
{
    my $line=<$fh>;
    chomp($line);
    print $line , "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.  For example, why are the `use` and `die` statements important?  Why is testing `eof()` better than testing `$line`?  These things aren't obvious to beginners and should be described.

Comment: I used this with the local file but the file is still not printing in the cmd prompt. I really don't know what is wrong but I have been trying to print this for nearly 10 hours.

Comment: do you get any output on cmd? or the problem is only when reading file?

Comment: When I try to open the file nothing is returned so I add a print statement at the end as a sanity check... this print statement did indeed print but nothing from the file printed.  It is strange because about a week ago I did the same thing but had no problem pulling in a local text file.  This particular file was saved locally but was from a url. When I opened the file from the url it printed just fine ... just not from the local file.  So I created a test.txt file with a bunch of text and tried to open and print that file and Zilch, nada, nothing printed.